# Displaying an item from a collection using Jradio button

Tags: java, swing, collections, jtextarea, jradiobutton

I been learning about java for some time now and even bought several books to help me along. i am now in at the point in my journey that i want to learn about collections. i am able to use array lists in a very basic ways but i would like to understand how they work when use in conjunction with J radio buttons and other swing components. I been working, watching YouTube videos and reading books such as "Introduction to Java Programming- Comprehensive, 10E" and "Java in a Nutshell - (6th E) O'Reilly " but i have not found the answer to my problem.  i can get the predefined information to display in the J text area by using the following code individually. "Person" calls a second class where I have my setters and getters.

```
private void LuisActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    Person Luis = new Person("Luis ", "Peres\n", 1953);
    Result.setText(String.valueOf(Luis));
}
```

But as you guys can see this is not using lists, instead i am writting each user individually in their individual action performed events. here is the code tha includes the collection/ list.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FinalProject extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public FinalProject() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        DisplayText = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        Exit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        ClearText = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Maria = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Jose = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Josh = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Dahn = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Terry = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Clark = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Sasha = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Paul = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Irlen = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Mary = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Puttin = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        James = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Jack = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Mark = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Jane = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Sal = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Perry = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Charley = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Anna = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        Bruce = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        DisplayText.setEditable(false);
        DisplayText.setColumns(20);
        DisplayText.setLineWrap(true);
        DisplayText.setRows(5);
        DisplayText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(DisplayText);

        Exit.setText("Exit");
        Exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ExitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        ClearText.setText("Clear Text");
        ClearText.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ClearTextActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(195, 205, 226));
        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 255), new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51)));

        buttonGroup1.add(Maria);
        Maria.setText("Maria");
        Maria.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                MariaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buttonGroup1.add(Jose);
        Jose.setText("Jose");
        Jose.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JoseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buttonGroup1.add(Josh);
        Josh.setText("Josh");
        Josh.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JoshActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buttonGroup1.add(Dahn);
        Dahn.setText("Dahn");
        Dahn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DahnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buttonGroup1.add(Terry);
        Terry.setText("Terry");

        buttonGroup1.add(Clark);
        Clark.setText("Clark");

        buttonGroup1.add(Sasha);
        Sasha.setText("Sasha");

        buttonGroup1.add(Paul);
        Paul.setText("Paul");

        buttonGroup1.add(Irlen);
        Irlen.setText("Irlen");

        buttonGroup1.add(Mary);
        Mary.setText("Mary");

        buttonGroup1.add(Puttin);
        Puttin.setText("Puttin");

        buttonGroup1.add(James);
        James.setText("James");

        buttonGroup1.add(Jack);
        Jack.setText("Jack");

        buttonGroup1.add(Mark);
        Mark.setText("Mark");

        buttonGroup1.add(Jane);
        Jane.setText("Jane");

        buttonGroup1.add(Sal);
        Sal.setText("Sal");

        buttonGroup1.add(Perry);
        Perry.setText("Perry");

        buttonGroup1.add(Charley);
        Charley.setText("Charley");

        buttonGroup1.add(Anna);
        Anna.setText("Anna");

        buttonGroup1.add(Bruce);
        Bruce.setText("Bruce");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Perry)
                    .addComponent(Jack)
                    .addComponent(Irlen)
                    .addComponent(Terry)
                    .addComponent(Maria))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Charley)
                    .addComponent(Mark)
                    .addComponent(Jose)
                    .addComponent(Clark)
                    .addComponent(Mary))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Anna)
                    .addComponent(Jane)
                    .addComponent(Puttin)
                    .addComponent(Sasha)
                    .addComponent(Josh))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Sal)
                    .addComponent(Paul)
                    .addComponent(James)
                    .addComponent(Dahn)
                    .addComponent(Bruce))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Josh)
                    .addComponent(Dahn)
                    .addComponent(Jose)
                    .addComponent(Maria))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Paul)
                    .addComponent(Sasha)
                    .addComponent(Clark)
                    .addComponent(Terry))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(James)
                    .addComponent(Puttin)
                    .addComponent(Mary)
                    .addComponent(Irlen))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Sal)
                    .addComponent(Jane)
                    .addComponent(Jack)
                    .addComponent(Mark))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Bruce)
                    .addComponent(Anna)
                    .addComponent(Charley)
                    .addComponent(Perry))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(ClearText)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Exit))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Exit)
                    .addComponent(ClearText))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        System.exit(0);
    }                                    

    private void ClearTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        DisplayText.setText("");
    }                                         

    private void MariaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      


    }                                     

    private void JoseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void JoshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void DahnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FinalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FinalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FinalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FinalProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FinalProject().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        // list where all user reside 
        List<Person> ml = new ArrayList<>();
        ml.add(new Person("Maria ", "Short\n", 2001));
        ml.add(new Person("Jose ", "White\n", 1980));
        ml.add(new Person("Josh ", "Brown\n", 1970));
        ml.add(new Person("Dahn ", "Lee\n", 1977));
        ml.add(new Person("Terry ", "Black\n", 1983));
        ml.add(new Person("Clark ", "Pale\n", 1999));
        ml.add(new Person("Sasha ", "Cole\n", 1989));
        ml.add(new Person("Paul ", "Chan\n", 1966));
        ml.add(new Person("Irlen ", "Bry\n", 1981));
        ml.add(new Person("Mary ", "Williams\n", 1975));
        ml.add(new Person("Puttin ", "Moreno\n", 1955));
        ml.add(new Person("James ", "Blanco\n", 1960));
        ml.add(new Person("Jack ", "Negro\n", 1963));
        ml.add(new Person("Mark ", "Torres\n", 1957));
        ml.add(new Person("Jane ", "Perez\n", 1995));
        ml.add(new Person("Sal ", "Salas\n", 1992));
        ml.add(new Person("Perry ", "Blah\n", 1973));
        ml.add(new Person("Charley ", "Nunca\n", 1996));
        ml.add(new Person("Anna ", "Cali\n", 2012));
        ml.add(new Person("Bruce ", "Cola\n", 2009));


    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Anna;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Bruce;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Charley;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Clark;
    private javax.swing.JButton ClearText;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Dahn;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea DisplayText;
    private javax.swing.JButton Exit;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Irlen;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Jack;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton James;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Jane;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Jose;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Josh;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Maria;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Mark;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Mary;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Paul;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Perry;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Puttin;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Sal;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Sasha;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton Terry;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Essentially what i want is for the user to be able to click on the Jradio button and the predefined data to appear in the jtextarea. Here is an alternative method that i am working on.

```
    class Storage{
    Person Juan = new Person("Juan ", "Short\n", 2001);
    Person Jose = new Person("Jose ", "White\n", 1980);
    Person Josh = new Person("Josh ", "Brown\n", 1970);
    Person Dahn = new Person("Dahn ", "Lee\n", 1977);
    Person Terry = new Person("Terry ", "Black\n", 1983);
    Person Clark = new Person("Clark ", "Pale\n", 1999);
    Person Sasha = new Person("Sasha ", "Cole\n", 1989);        
    Person Paul = new Person("Paul ", "Chan\n", 1966);
    Person Irlen = new Person("Irlen ", "Bry\n", 1981);
    Person Mary = new Person("Mary ", "Williams\n", 1975);
    Person Puttin = new Person("Puttin ", "Moreno\n", 1955);
    Person James = new Person("James ", "Blanco\n", 1960);
    Person Jack = new Person("Jack ", "Negro\n", 1963);
    Person Mark = new Person("Mark ", "Torres\n", 1957);
    Person Jane = new Person("Jane ", "Perez\n", 1995);
    Person Sal = new Person("Sal ", "Salas\n", 1992);
    Person Perry = new Person("Perry ", "Blah\n", 1973);
    Person Charley = new Person("Charley ", "Nunca\n", 1996);
    Person Anna = new Person("Anna ", "Cali\n", 2012);
    Person Bruce = new Person("Bruce ", "Cola\n", 2009);

     List<Person> ml = new ArrayList<>();

     protected Storage (){
         ml.add(Juan);

         ml.add(Jose); // and so on..
```

But again I can't figure out how to connect my Jradio button the predefined information, so that when the user click on the radio button the information displays in the JtextArea.

Comment: Why can't you replace `Result.setText(String.valueOf(Luis));` with `ml.add(Luis)`? But you should check the selected state of the `JRadioButton`...

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  2) There is no `?` in that mess of words.  Do you have a question?  If so, can you (add it and) add a question mark as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28892805/edit)? 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently

Comment: To answer your question when I place “ml.add(Juan);” in the Performed action area I get two errors 
1) Cannot find symbol: variable ml , location: FinalProject 
2) Cannot find symbol: variable Juan, location: FinalProject
I can't figure out how to get this to work

Comment: My apologies MadProgrammer last i posted something several users complained that i was not giving enough information. I would like to know how do i get my collection to display the correct information when the user clicks on the Jradio button. example if the user click on Jradio Button "Juan" the information regarding "Juan" would display on JtextArea.

Answer (score 1):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. I doubt your O'Rielly text book uses upper case characters.

Instead of storing your Person object in an ArrayList you can store then in a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Person> people = new HashMap<String, Person>();
people.put("Juan", new Person("Juan ", "Short\n", 2001));
people.put("Jose", new Person("Jose ", "White\n", 1980));
```

Now you can write a common ActionListener to be shared by all radio buttons:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        Person person = people.get(command);
    }
};
```

Once you have the Person object you can display the data from the Person in you text area.

Also, you shouldn't create the buttons one at a time. Instead create a Array (or ArrayList) of the names you want to use and then iterate through the Array. Something like:

```
String[] names = 
{
    "Juan",
    "Jose"
};

for (String name: names)
{
    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(name);
    button.addActionListener( al );
    panel.add( button );
}
```

Comment: First i will like to apologies for wasting your time it was not my intention. the object Person in  " Person Luis = new Person("Luis ", "Peres\n", 1953); "  refers to the class where i have my setters and getters. Again i am sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @AbrahamEsparza, I know. Once you have the Person object you can use getName() getter method to get the name of the person and display the name in your text area.

Comment: dear camickr thank you so much for your feedback, i want you to know that i really appreciate you taking the time to review my program. I am new to programming and its probably very aggravating for real programmers to see the same mistakes over and over and for that i am sorry. I will study very hard so that someday i am able to give back to the community. Again thank you so very much