# Drawing a Label Containing an Icon Showing a Circle

Tags: java, swing, icons

So I am trying to draw a label which contains an icon showing a circle. The circle will initially be filled red, and then depending on which of the 3 buttons I press, it will either change to green, blue, or red using repaint.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class ColorChanger implements Icon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        JButton redButton = new JButton("Red");
        JButton greenButton = new JButton("Green");
        JButton blueButton = new JButton("Blue");
        Graphics g;

        ColorChanger myCircle = new ColorChanger();
        final JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(myCircle);

    //  myCircle.paintIcon(myFrame, g, 50, 50);

        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200; 

        myFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        myFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        myFrame.add(redButton);
        myFrame.add(greenButton);
        myFrame.add(blueButton);
        myFrame.add(myLabel);

        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 10, 10);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(circle);
    }    
}
```

My issue is, I have no idea what to pass for the Graphics g in paintIcon. Is there a different way to do this? I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: The icon will be painted automatically by the `JLabel` when it things it needs to be updated...

Comment: [maybe a shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14253786/714968)

Comment: @MadProgrammer But it's not painting it. I'm getting the 3 buttons to show up, but now the circle.

Comment: A complete example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Thanks! That looks like a very useful post. I'll be sure to reference it when working on mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 10, 10);
```

The size of the icon is (10, 10). 50, is outside the bounds of the Icon.  Painting is done relative to the icon so the ellipse should be:

```
Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

> it will either change to green, blue, or red using repaint.

Your ColorChanger class will need a `setColor(Color color)` method so that you can dynamically change the color to be painted. The paintIcon() method should then use this color.

Comment: @aurora91, glad it helped. You should "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Done and done. Thanks @AndrewThompson for the link. I'm gonna be honest, I wasn't quick sure where the "accept" button was.